# How to get extracts for all returned pages by Wikipedia API?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I am using the sandbox to find out how I can use extracts property to retrieve the first sentence in all pages (limit 10) with title Amsterdam, but as you can see in the sandbox the extracts property is only working on the first retrieved page.

How can I get extracts for all the returned pages?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=info|extracts&generator=search&exsentences=1&exintro=1&gsrsearch=Amsterdam&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`exlimit`](https://bg.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts) for `prop=extracts` (max value is 20, default is 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=info|extracts&generator=search&exsentences=1&exintro=1&gsrsearch=Amsterdam&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&exlimit=10